# Google's jsapi - google is undefined error in IE only

Tags: internet-explorer, google-visualization

I'm using Google's `jsapi` to draw charts. My charts work when I view my page with FireFox, but in IE I get the following error in my console:

```
SCRIPT5009: 'google' is undefined
```

This is how my code looks in the `head` tag of my HTML document:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
</script>
```

But it fails on the `google.load` call.

The only "solution" I could find was changing the URL protocol from `http` to `https`. My site isn't using `https` other places. I tried using it anyway for `jsapi`, but that error kept showing up in IE.

Answer (score 0):

If loading https://www.google.com/jsapi in a new Internet Explorer tab gives you an error message about TLS, you [need to enable it](http://www.bauer-power.net/2014/06/how-to-enabled-tls-11-and-tls-12-in.html).

The good news is that it only affected your computer. The bad news is that the fix is client-side and you can't enable TLS for your site's visitors.

Answer (score -1):

Internet Explorer has some issues while reading the js code. The most probable reason for your problem is that IE does not handle well the line breaks in your code. If you try something like this it will work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});</script>
```