# Google chart not displaying in IE 8

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

The code below displays a stacked bar graph. It works well with Chrome and Firefox. However, IE does not display the chart. I know IE is very sensitive to extra commas and other typos. I spent quite a bit of time looking at this code with the IE developer tools but I could not figure out why it does not show. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="" content="">
<meta name="vs_targetSchema" content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5">
<!-- CHARTS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        //================
        //Historical tiers CHART
        //================
       var data_history = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Tiers', 'Baseline', 'Tier 2', 'Tier 3', 'Tier 4','Tier 5', 
        { role: 'annotation' } ],
        ['1', 121, 18, 0, 0, 0, '138' ], ['2', 109, 31, 0, 0, 0, '140' ], ['3', 121, 18, 0, 0, 0, '138' ], ['4', 117, 37, 0, 0, 0, '154' ], ['5', 121, 18, 0, 0, 0, '138' ], ['6', 74, 25, 95, 0, 0, '194' ], ['7', 76, 26, 88, 0, 0, '190' ], ['8', 76, 26, 88, 0, 0, '190' ], ['9', 74, 25, 95, 0, 0, '194' ], ['10', 76, 26, 88, 0, 0, '190' ], ['11', 117, 22, 0, 0, 0, '139' ], ['12', 121, 18, 0, 0, 0, '138' ]       
      ]);

      var options = {
        width: 800,
        height: 300,
        legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
        bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
        isStacked: true
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_historical'));
        chart.draw(data_history, options);


}
</script>
<style>
.chart{
background-color:red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>chart</h1>

<div class=chart id="chart_historical" style="width: 850px; height: 340px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It rendered in IE8 for me.  (The label font was cursive and a little hard to read.)

Comment: That code looks fine for the most part; the only problem I can see is that your chart div's class attribute is missing quotes, but I don't think that would cause your chart to fail in IE8.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28348071/241211) help you?